# Imputation introduces negative values when using imputePCA() from the missMDA package in R?

Tags: pca, missing-data, data-imputation

I am testing out various imputation methods on my data and would like to use imputePCA. It imputes the missing values with no error messages, but when I check the completeObs matrix some of the imputed values are negative. The original matrix has no negative values and the minimum value this type of data can have is 0. One of the variables that gets negative values after imputation has 30% missing values, the whole data set has ~15% missing values. Why do I get negative values and how can I prevent this?

My R code is:

```
estim_ncpPCA(data, ncp.min=0, ncp.max=12, threshold=1e-6)
data.imp_iPCA <- imputePCA(data, ncp=4, scale=TRUE, method="Regularized")
```

I first estimate the number of components and then use that value in the imputePCA function. There seems to be no argument to set a minimum value for imputed data for this function.